# Problema al descargar un xml para después mostrar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

tengo un problemilla que me tiene ya un tiempo mareado, y os comento, para empezar, tengo el permiso de Internet en el manifest, y a la hora de coger el archivo xml (todo ocurre dentro de un asyntask), la línea que corresponde al InputStream, se la salta y ya no hace nada más, no sé si se la salta o si entra en un bucle infinito, en resumen, intento coger datos de aemet (el estadocielo) pero no consigo avanzar de aquí, con averiguar qué ocurre daré un pase importante, con las capturas se verá mejor mi problema. Estoy probando la aplicación desde un android 9.0 pie, que es lo único que tengo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Que error se muestra en el LogCat? ¿Que caracteristicas tiene el dispositivo donde sucede el problema? agrega información a tu pregunta, revisa [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Vale, la solución es que a partir de android 8.0 el texto plano no cifrado no está permitido, tan fácil como añadir esto:

Comment: que es lo que hay que añadir?

Comment: realiza tus respuesta basándote en [answer] para que sean de mayor ayuda a la comunidad, modifica esta respuesta agregando más información.